# Past simple or past continuous for process in the past?

Tags: past-tense, simple-past

Let's say that I have a computer program that had been doing one thing, but later that program was changed. Which statement would be more correct?

> It was sorting by errors, but now it's sorting by warnings.

or

> It sorted by errors, but now it sorts by warnings.

And what if didn't have that second part?

> It sorted by errors.

This sounds like it was just one time action and not the way that program worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is to employ ***used to***:

> We use *used to + infinitive* to talk about ***a past situation that is no longer true***. It tells us that there was a repeated action or state in the past which has now changed. ([BBClearnenglish](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/used-to-infinitive-and-be-or-get-used-to-ing))

So your sentence could be written as:

> It ***used to*** sort by errors(, but now it *sorts* by warnings).

The parenthesis can be omitted, and the idea of change still remains. A past habitual action is replaced by a present habitual action, so present tense simple is more indicated in the clause between the parenthesis.